# Validation for custom date / time format

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I apply validation for my *"time"* like this:

```
With sh.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(8).DataBodyRange.Validation
  .Add Type:=xlValidateTime, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="0:00:00", Formula2:="23:59:59"
  .ErrorMessage = "Enter time as hh:mm:ss"
End With
```

And this will only take *"time"* in format `HH:MM:SS`.

Now I want to change this so that I can input *"date time"* in my custom format
`dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS`.

So I read a bit and found out that Excel stores *"date time"* as a decimal number, so I tried to change my code like this (note that I used `Type:=xlValidateDecimal`):

```
sh.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(9).DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

With sh.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(9).DataBodyRange.Validation
  .Add Type:=xlValidateDecimal, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="01/01/2000 0:00:00", Formula2:=Date & " " & "23:59:59"
  .ErrorMessage = "Date time must be in format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss with date after 01/01/2000 and time between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59."
End With
```

This works for *"date"* which can't be earlier than `01/01/2000` but it does not work for the *"time"* which can be inputted as `25:00:00` and it will still work by advancing one day and setting time to `01:00:00`. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Does `ListColumns(8)` contain actual dates, and what is the NumberFormat applied to that range?

Comment: @TimWilliams Number format is ˙`General` for all the columns in the table. What do you mean by *"actual dates"*?

Comment: Sometimes cells are formatted as "Text", or may have content that looks like a date but which excel does not recognize as a date (eg. because the user entered "12/24/2022" and the system default date format is "dd/mm/yyy" so "24" is not a valid month)

Comment: @TimWilliams Please check my modified question.